# Task gets stuck in "[Scheduled and Waiting to Run]"

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I've run into an issue with tasks I can't seem to figure out. This application makes repeated HTTP calls via WebClient to several servers. It maintains a dictionary of tasks that are running the HTTP calls, and every five seconds it checks for results, then once the results are in it makes an HTTP call again. This goes on for the lifetime of the application.

Recently, it has started having a problem where the tasks are randomly getting stuck in WaitingForActivation. In the debugger the task shows as "[Scheduled and waiting to run]", but it never runs.
[image: Task in "scheduled and waiting to run"]

This is the function that it's running, when I click on the "Scheduled" task in the debugger, it points to the DownloadStringTaskAsync() line:

```cs
private static async Task<string> DownloadString(string url)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient()) {
        try {
            var result = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return result;
        } catch (WebException) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The code that is actually creating the task that runs the above function is this. It only hits this line once the existing task is completed, Task.IsCompleted never returns true since it's stuck in scheduled status. Task.Status gets stuck in WaitingForActivation.

```cs
tasks[resource] = Task.Run(() => DownloadString("http://" + resources[resource] + ":8181/busy"));
```

The odd thing about this is that, as far as I can tell, this code ran perfectly fine for two years, until we recently did a server migration which included an upgraded OS and spawned a network packet loss issue. That's when we started noticing this particular problem, though I don't see how either of those would be related.

Also, this tends to only happen after the application has been running for several thousand seconds. It runs perfectly fine for a while until tasks, one-by-one, start getting stuck. After about a day, there's usually four or five tasks stuck in scheduled. Since it usually takes time for the first task to get stuck, that seems to me like there would be a race condition of some sort, but I don't see how that could be the case.

Is there a reason a task would get stuck in scheduled and never actually run?

Comment: `WaitingForActivation` is not "Scheduled and waiting to run" - are you sure you're looking at the same tasks? Tasks in `WaitingForActivation` for a while is perfectly normal and nothing to be concerned about. Tasks in `WaitingToRun` for a while usually indicates a saturated thread pool.

Comment: In the screenshot, task ID 94035 was the task that was stored in the "tasks" dictionary, and looking at the status in the debugger it came up as WaitingForActivation. All three of those tasks listed are related; the debugger shows the three of them together when hovering the cursor over one of them.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Understand why some Thread didn't start in the code where you don't need a Thread, or make the software work? Remove wrapping `Task.Run` and check it again. To answer the initial question need more information e.g. how many tasks are working at once. What happens later, after Task is completed (do you remove it from dictionary? Concurrent dictionary?), what kind of TaskSceduler is in use, what is environment, etc. In other words only the reproducible example can help me to find out what originally happens. Btw, have you any feedback related to my answer?

Comment: One more thing: `WebClient` creates new TCP connection per request, you may run out of sockets this way. Then `HttpClient` from the answer may help because it can reuse the opened connections. Give it a try.

Comment: As far as what I'm looking for, I'd like to understand why exactly the task isn't starting so I can gain some additional knowledge from this, but I could settle for getting the application working properly. There are a lot of tasks going on in the code, there's about a dozen showing scheduled/running at any given moment (about half of those are related to this code). After the task is completed, on the next five second cycle it'll start a new one - that same `task[resource]` line will run replacing the completed task with a new one. It's a non-concurrent dictionary.

Comment: I don't have any task scheduler in use - I just have a lot of Task.Run() and async/await littered about. (Pretty sure a lot of those are unnecessary.) Environment is a Windows 2016 server, project is targeting framework 4.6.1, the application normally runs as a Windows service although while I've been debugging it I've been running it through Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ancient `WebClient` (maybe it contains bugs) but can suggest the recommended by Microsoft way to get a response from a server using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`. Also `HttpClient` is rather faster works with multiple requests per endpoint, especially in .NET Core/.NET 5.

```cs
// HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

private static async Task<string> DownloadString(string url)
{
    try
    {
        return await client.GetStringAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also remove `Task.Run`, it's a kind of redundancy.

```cs
tasks[resource] = DownloadString($"http://{resources[resource]}:8181/busy");
```

[Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) - read the article. You have to get a difference between I/O-bound and CPU-bound work, and don't spawn Threads without special need for concurrency. You need [no Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) here.

Comment: I did implemented your suggestions. Removing the extraneous Task.Run() has removed an unnecessary task (the debugger only shows the two related ones instead of three), though that by itself did not fix the issue. Waiting to see if HttpClient makes a difference.

Comment: @Nicholas `did not fix the issue` - thus the source of the "Task" problem is outside of the shown code, maybe inside the `WebClient`, not sure.

Comment: @Nicholas The [original reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14642612/12888024) of WaitingToRun - probably `ThreadPool` is full. The removing `Task.Run()` should partially solve the problem. And yes, `HttpClient` may help because it more wiseful using Threads. You may limit the maximum amount of active jobs e.g. using `SemaphoreSlim` with a loop which starting jobs.

Comment: Using HttpClient instead of WebClient fixed the issue. I am curious what was going on under the hood, but the tasks are no longer getting stuck.

Comment: @Nicholas `WebClient` is too old and can contain bugs e.g. of regression type while `HttpClient` is currently officially recommended and supported API. Expected things.